# React onMouseOver doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onmouseover

I want to fire an event when the mouse moves over a `div`.
I am using `React` as my front end framework, and following their [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html), the event just doesn't fire.

```
<div onMouseOver={console.log('onMouseOver')} onMouseOut={console.log('onMouseOut')} className="hidden-xs text-center">
      {productImage}
      {productContent}
</div>
```

When the page is loading, I see in the console full of log output from onMouseOver and onMouseOut, but when I move my mouse over the element (`div`), nothing else is written.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should assign the reference of the methods instead of calling them in event registers. Try this :

```
handleOnMouseOver: function(e){
  console.log("onMouseOver");
}
....
<div onMouseOver={this.handleOnMouseOver} ..../> // NOTE : don't put () at the end
```

Answer (score 3):

To expand on Phil's answer -- whatever you put in the braces `{}` is evaluated at the time the component is being mounted.  If you put

```
onMouseOver={console.log("onMouseOver")}
```

then as the component is mounting, React evaluates the expression by executing `console.log()` which returns `undefined`, so the handler is set to `undefined`.

If you put

```
onMouseOver={this.handleOnMouseOver}
```

the expression evaluates to a reference to the handler, so you get what you want.  You can also use

```
onMouseOver={() => console.log("mouseOver")}
```